# Cannot Parse Variables from RowEditing to RowUpdating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble getting the values of public variables **file** and **desc** set on the **RowEditing** method.

I have put a break-point at the end of the **RowEditing** and i can see that the **file** and **desc** values are being set, but when i click on **Update** these values on RowUpdating are being set back to **""**.

The gridDok.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text is also being set to **""** and i get the **ArgumentExceprion**:

**String cannot be of zero length.
Parameter name: oldValue**

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Here is the code of the methods:

```
protected void gridDok_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    file = gridDok.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[5].Text;
    desc = gridDok.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[4].Text;
}

protected void gridDok_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string file1 = file.Replace(desc, gridDok.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text);
    File.Move("~/" + file, "~/" + file1);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, global variables are not retained across postbacks - store them via:

```
Session["file"] = gridDok.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[5].Text;
```

and retrieve them via:

```
var file = Session["file"] as string;
if (file != null) { .. }
```

HTH.